# How to fix "Bot object has no attribute logs_from"

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've been trying to make a bot using discord.py, I want to make a command that deletes x number of messages. However, logs_from is not recognized as an attribute for the bot object.

I searched online and everyone seemed to have no problem using logs_from.

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

Client = discord.Client() 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

@bot.command(pass_context=True,)
async def purge(ctx, number):
    number = int(number)
    if number > 99 or number < 1:
        await ctx.send("I can only delete messages within a range of 1 - 99")
    else:
        author = ctx.message.author
        authorID = author.id
        mgs = []
        number = int(number)
        channel = ctx.message.channel
        async for x in bot.logs_from((channel), limit = int(number+1)):
            mgs.append(x)
        await delete_messages(mgs)
        await ctx.send('Messages deleted!', delete_after=4)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the stateful model changes, `Client.logs_from` has been replaced with [`Messageable.history`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.history).

If you're trying to adapt old materials into the newer versions of discord.py, you should read the [migration guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html).